# JSON array object to be in object push

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I am using lodash here for JSON object manipulation:

```
[{"a": "apple"}, {"b":"ball"}]
```

Expected:

```
{a: "apple", b: "ball"}
```

Let me know the best way to get in done. Best one thanks appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

With vanilla JS you can spread into object assign:

```js
const result = Object.assign({}, ...[{"a": "apple"}, {"b":"ball"}]);

console.log(result);
```

With lodash you can do the use `_.assign()`, but you'll need to partial apply an empty array, and use `_.spread()`, so it can handle an array:

```js
const combine = _.spread(_.partialRight(_.assign, {}));

const arr = [{"a": "apple"}, {"b":"ball"}];

const result = combine(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Accepted! spread unpack JSON object assigning.

Comment: I've added a lodash solution as well.

Comment: Don't know why `false` public making it downvoted. Be `true`.